# How can I match the behavior of from_dataframe with from_file for bigquery load jobs with data which has missing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, google-bigquery

If I create an empty table in bigquery with a column which has a default value, when I load data with a missing column from_dataframe the default value is fulfilled but when I try to do the same from_file I get a BadRequest error.

How can I achieve the same behaviour with load_table_from_file?

**Working Example**

```py
# Create an empty table with a column which has a default value

dataset_id = 'test'
table_id = 'test'

cols = ['source', 'ts']
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

bq_client = bigquery.Client()

schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField('source', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE'), 
        bigquery.SchemaField('ts', 'TIMESTAMP', 'NULLABLE', default_value_expression='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()') 
    ]

dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=schema
)

job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_ref, job_config=job_config
)
job.result()
```

**Load from dataframe**

```py
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'source':['dataframe']})

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND'
)

job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_ref, job_config=job_config
)

job.result()
```

Result:

[image: Table with default value furfilled]

**Load table from csv**

```py
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'source':['csv']})

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format = 'CSV',
    skip_leading_rows = 1
)

dataframe.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
with open('temp.csv', "rb") as source_file:
    job = bq_client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config
    )

job.result()
```

Result:

```
BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1 columns.
```

How can I match the behaviour of from_dataframe with from_file? For context, I would like to use this method to created an updated_at field with the ingestion time of the row.

**Update**

If `allow_jagged_rows = True` is added to the job config for the csv, the data is loaded but the result is NULL in the ts column, not the default value of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the below code to Load CSV data from Cloud Storage into a table.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

To Import a local file you refer to this [code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-from-file).

For more information you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table).

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question. I am asking how to upload a csv which has missing trailing columns to a table which already exists and how to make those columns accept the default values as shown in the reproducible example above.